# UBUNTU 14.04 64BIT can not install lib32stdc++6

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt-get, libstdc++

I want install a 32bit application,but i can not install lib32stdc++6
here is:

sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: @MrLister,i used this method,but can not solved my problem,maybe we will get a better one

Comment: This link solved my issue without using aptitude to downgrade.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/671791/lib32stdc6-package-depends-on-gcc-base-but-my-installed-version-is-newer

Answer (score 0):

finally，i found this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages
and i use aptitude to force install this

sudo aptitude -f install lib32stdc++6

run this command ,and choose 'n',then it will give you another choice,then choose 'Y'.
done and success